# Is there any way to control read/write speed or IOPS limit per pod?

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, we can control CPU, memory, and disk size. But is there any way to control the IOPS limit or read/write speed per pod?

Because one of the POD's heavy read/write operations might affect other pod performance.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible currently, but there is an ongoing work in that matter:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/92287